# Error Appstore connect : Missing Purpose String in Info.plist File

Tags: ios, app-store, expo, appstore-approval, info.plist

I've submitted my app for review to the App Store Connect. Although the app is still under review, I've received an email to inform me that I have to fix an error. Here is the content of the message:

> Dear Developer,
>
> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your  app
>   XXXXX. Your delivery was successful, but you  may wish to correct the
>   following issues in your next delivery:
>
> "Missing Purpose String in Info.plist File. Your app's code 
>   references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The 
>   app's Info.plist file should contain a 
>   NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose 
>   string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the  data.
>   Starting spring 2019, all apps submitted to the App Store  that access
>   user data will be required to include a purpose  string.If you're
>   using external libraries or SDKs, they may  reference APIs that
>   require a purpose string. While your app might  not use these APIs, a
>   purpose string is still required. You can  contact the developer of
>   the library or SDK and request they  release a version of their code
>   that doesn't contain the APIs.
>
> After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or   Application
>   Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.
>
> Best regards,
>
> The App Store Team

My app is fully built with Expo and I don't know how to access and modify the Info.plist.

Any idea?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the latest build, given that I don't even use Location Services in my app. And Apple has no official document about this change.

Comment: Same issue here, not changed the Info.plist either

Comment: Same issue. I just did a tiny change and a new build and got this. I do have an `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in the Info.plist that is blank but I have translation strings for it.

Comment: +1 Did a release for the same app 2 days ago and everything is fine. 2 days later, just changed a couple of lines of code to do a new release (didn't add more Pods or something like that) and I got this message

Comment: We've experienced the same issue. I suspect it's a bug in the approval process (hopefully). I'm going to ignore for the weekend and hope that it's fixed on Monday.

Comment: I faced the same exact issue just now although our App doesn't really need Location Services Always. It just needs NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription which we already have a purpose string for. Probably this is just a glitch on Apple's end?

Comment: And in Apple-fashion, the link they provide in the email to fix it, is broken.

Comment: Do we have to re-archive after updating the info.plist ?

Comment: I also got the same issue. I installed `ionic diagnostic` plugin and got this `NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription`   in the Info.plist

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you're using Expo, you can add solve by adding infoPlist to app.json like so:

```
  "expo": {
     "ios": {
       "bundleIdentifier": "com.app.myapp",
       "infoPlist": {
         "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription": "Some message to appease Apple.",
       },
     },
   }
```

[Expo Docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/app-stores)

Comment: Actually it is **NOT** "some message to appease Apple" but to let the user know WHAT are you doing with the user's generated data (location) in this case. It is a matter of privacy concerns and I do think it is good to be fair to your apps users.

Comment: Gotcha! I was thinking to newbies that may be tempted to leave it so! I did not want to sound grumpy :) cheers!

Comment: @gwalshington I don't have any expo object in app.json

Comment: @HeemanshuBhalla hmm, i'm unsure why. In my app.json, it's at the top and the first object declared. It's where you declare the version number, bundle identifier, etc. If you have ejected the app, maybe it looks slightly different?

Comment: What text to type if we don't collect and Location data? We need to make up a lie :S

Comment: @PrimožKralj Yes unfortunately - I don't collect location data, but it forced me to provide a message.

Comment: @Lookaji since Google is not asking for it, as a Flutter dev, I AM doing it just to please Apple. Hence I don't even know if the <string>  gets translated I'll have to figure this out

Answer (score 83):

**EDIT April 2019** : You now have to add these two keys, as spring 2019 has begun. Note that `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` is now deprecated (since iOS 11) and has been replaced with `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription` and `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`. If you want to support lower than iOS 11, you'll have to use the three values.

**To sum up you have to:**

- Add `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription` AND `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` for iOS 11 and more
- And add `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` if you want to support iOS 10 and less
- And finally, you can add `NSLocationUsageDescription` if you wan to support iOS 8 and less.

## <strike>You can submit your app even if you got this message !</strike>

I’ve just faced the same issue yesterday, even if the app isn’t using the location functionality. It may be related to some framework included in the project that have this optional feature.

**I can confirm that my app has been approved** even without the `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` key in `info.plist`

Indeed, as Apple stated in the mail :

> Starting spring 2019, all apps submitted to the App Store 
>       that access user data will be required to include a purpose 
>       string.

So the only thing to do is to add this key (right now is better, so that you won’t forget) in you project so that it will be included **in your next update**.

Just add two new entries in your `info.plist`, with `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` as keys and a short description of why you use them as the value (even if you don’t really use them...).

Comment: In your April 2019 edit, are you sure you don't have the deprecation reversed? From what I see NSLocationUsageDescription is the one that's deprecated. Looking here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW18

Comment: The email I received from apple mentions NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription so i think he has it reversed.

Comment: @apricity @DrorBar Sorry guys, indeed I had made a mistake. It was not reversed but there was still a mistake, `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` should be replaced by `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription` and `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription `, and not by `NSLocationUsageDescription` (as I previously wrote, sorry…). I've updated my answer to add a sum up of the process.

Answer (score 56):

I have some apps in the store and I tried to distribute a version for QA and the same thing happened in two different Apps.
I think this is a new criteria to accept the builds uploads to Appstore connect.

The solution is simple, add the following lines in the .plist file.

`<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key> 

<string>custom message</string> 

<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key> 

<string>custom message</string>`

PS: In my case have not using any feature of location, but I added these lines in order to comply with Appstore connect guidelines. Btw after receive that email, I could test the app even when they said that build it had some issues.

I hope this work for you guys.

Comment: Wow, I just got this, realized everyone is just getting this too!

Comment: first key has changed as of now to `<key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>`

Comment: Do we have to re-archive after updating the info.plist ?

Comment: Do I have to increase the bundle version or version number to upload a new binary?

Comment: @BishoyHanna YES! Dror Bar YES!

Answer (score 23):

It's a new requirement from apple, even if you do not use location. If you want to add the permissions in Xcode, look for "Privacy - Location Usage Description" and "Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description" and type a custom string for each of them.

[image]

Comment: In other app update, Apple requested this permission too: "Privacy - Location Always Usage Description"

Comment: So if I don't use these features, what I have to write there, a lie, something like "collect location for future use, maybe"?

Comment: yes, apple will reach to you if they have questions

Comment: I am not able to find **Information Property List** in my xcode 10.1, you should have mentioned where to find it, I have looked for Build Settings both for Targets and Project

Comment: Okay So Targets->Info->Custom ios Target Properties was the exact location

Answer (score 22):

For more simplifying you can add these lines in your info.plist. These error are coming because **Starting spring 2019, all apps submitted to the App Store that access user data will be required to include a purpose string.**

1. Open info.plist as source code.
2. Add these following lines in your plist

   ```
   <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
   <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) needs Location access for "some reason"!</string>
   <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
   <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) needs Location access for "some reason"!</string>
   <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
   <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) needs Location access for "some reason"!</string>
   ```

Comment: I had to remove extra spaces in <key> tags and then it worked.

Comment: @innich thank you for pointing it out, I have changed my answer.

Answer (score 11):

> "Missing Purpose String in Info.plist File. Your app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist file should contain a NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. Starting spring 2019, all apps submitted to the App Store that access user data will be required to include a purpose string.If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of their code that doesn't contain the APIs.

Open `Info.plist` as source code.
Add these following lines in your plist

```html
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) needs Location access for "some reason"!</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) needs Location access for "some reason"!</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) needs Location access for "some reason"!</string>
```

Answer (score 9):

##Use this key in info.plist file

NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
Your location is required for xyz benefits for you    NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
Your location is required for xyz benefits for you

Answer (score 8):

We did receive the same email and we aren't using the CoreLocation at all. After a quick search, we found that Parse SDK could use CoreLocation. In Apple's email, they clearly say:

> If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string.

That mean the minute your code or any other Library or SDKs can use CoreLocation, even if you don't use it, you need to provide privacy description for "When In Use" and "Always Use".

It is also something new from Apple and for now it's only a warning but it will be required starting in Spring 2019 for new submissions.

Comment: It's just stupid.... If I'm not using it, it could make peoples dont downloading my app just because of that. -_-

Comment: Not really. The alert asking you to use your localization won't show unless somewhere in the code the `CLLocationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` is called. Apple analyzed each app code to see if such a function could be called. If it's never called, the alert won't show up.

Answer (score 7):

There are the following cases:

```
NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription (iOS>11)
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription          (iOS>11)
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription             (iOS<=10)
NSLocationUsageDescription                   (seems very old, iOS8?)
```

Apple states at:

> Add the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` key and the `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription` key to your *Info.plist* file.

and:

> If your app supports iOS 10 and earlier, add the `NSLocationAlwaysUsage`

`NSLocationUsageDescription` seems dead, the only ref in ADC site is:
https://developer.apple.com/ibeacon/Getting-Started-with-iBeacon.pdf

So to be sure, use first 3.

Answer (score 6):

This issue is occurring because you haven't included

```
 <NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription>
```

for your app. I faced the same issue when I tried to submit my app on the AppStore. After the app was processed, I got the same mail. I just added the description and now its resolved.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This helped me. If you are using Location in your app (or maybe just always) you need to add this line and a string below it.

`<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Always And In Use Permission</string>`

Answer (score 4):

These answers all tell you how to comply with the App Store rules to avoid the warning but the true fix would be for Expo to allow you to disable their SDKs requirement for Location Services unless you actually use them - I'm not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 4):

Please review the email you received from **App Store Connect **

**Identify The Missing Key**
[image]

Instructions

1. Open info.plist file.
2. Add and search for the missing key from the options provided (e.g. **Contacts** = Privacy - Contacts Usage Description)
3. Add Usage Description:

> $(PRODUCT_NAME) needs Contacts access to "Provide The Reason Here".

Example:
[image]

Comment: sir i got same error but why add to info.plist actually i m not used contact feature in my app so why we need to add it?

Comment: @Kapilsoni Please ensure you are not accessing one or more APIs that has access to sensitive user data

Comment: :sir I have used only camera and location in my app?

Answer (score 3):

same issue in Feb 19, got an email with a bunch of permissions I am not using, I assume they are from plugins. Apple says in March 19 it is a requirement so I am adding these in info.plst and uploading again.

It is very silly indeed.

Comment: More of a comment really...?

Answer (score 3):

I had 
`<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription </key>`
instead of
`<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>`

be sure to remove trailing whitespace

Answer (score 3):

I also face the same issue but after 27 hours, I received the email about approved even I did nothing. **So wait for approximately 24 hours instead of doing all this process again.**

Comment: Yes, it’s a bug!

Answer (score 3):

With Xcode 11 copy the key `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and add this to `Info` -> `Custom iOS Target Properties` -> Click `+` in the bottom left of this tab and as a value insert some kind of description like `This app requires location access to function properly.`.

Answer (score 1):

My app also got that， and I do nothing about it but it can run well ,next time I think should add such key in plist,just do some description

Answer (score 1):

A short answer to the above problem -

`NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` must be updated with the following description in Info.plist file

> {Your App Name} requires access to the location to suggest dengue
>   outbreak zones.

Answer (score 1):

In our case, we were using `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in our app, but not `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`.

Reading from the comments [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-geolocation/issues/25) (thanks matt-oakes), it looks like `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` is being used by one of the dependency frameworks we use.

Running our app it doesn't show the actual NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription permission modal, so it looks to just handle this in the background.

So in summary, adding `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` to the Info.plist fixed the warning email, and did not change any behaviour in the app