# ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, info.plist, ios-permissions

Deploying the app on testFlight I'm having the following issue,

> The app's Info.plist file should contain a
> NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string
> explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data.

Even if I have include on the Info.plist file the keys needed for the location access.

The app is submitted for review and tests but I'm still getting an email on every submit that says:

> Version: 1.0.2 Build: 74) has one or more issues

I've checked the solution here in order to add the deprecated keys too

[image]

[Error Appstore connect : Missing Purpose String in Info.plist File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52002466/error-appstore-connect-missing-purpose-string-in-info-plist-file)

Sorry, perhaps I'm missing something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click on your  `Info.plist` file. then click on 'Open As' -> 'Source Code'.

Now find and replace below keys,

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>your description.</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>your description</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>your description.</string>
```

Property list view of your `info.plist` is not showing like

```
Privacy - Location always and when In Use Usage Description

Privacy - Location always Usage Description
```

Instead it is showing `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription` and `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`

Comment: Yes that solved the issue, thank you!

I delete the previous one write it again as Privacy - Location always Usage Description on the key fields. For the other ones it makes an automatic update of the name for example: 

NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription to -> Privacy - Location always and when In Use Usage Description.


 //  But for this one _**NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription**_ only I made it ***manually*** 
 to ***Privacy - Location always Usage Description*** and it works fine! 
I deployed and didn't get the Version: 1.0.2 Build: xx has one or more issues email again!