# Flutter : get rejected by using geolocator in both ios and android

Tags: android, ios, flutter, publish, getlocation

I have flutter app using geolocator, the app rejected in both appStore and playStore, my AndroidManifest.xml contain these permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

and info.plist containe these :

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to location when in the background.</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to location when open.</string>
```

the app is rejected from both, in android get these steps to do :

> -To continue using location in the background, submit or update your Developer Permission Declaration along with a compliant version of
> your app in the Play Console for approval.
>
> -If your app is not eligible to access location in the background or does not meet requirements for accessing location in the background,
> please remove the permission from your manifest and in-app
> functionality.

in iOS get this :

> Please revise the purpose string in your app’s Info.plist file for the
> location to explain why your app needs access and include an example
> of how the user's data will be used.

How can I fix this issue, can't understand exactly what must I want to do.

Comment: Your purpose string describes *what* your app does, not *why it needs location*. I don't know what your app does, but consider a ride share type of app. It would say something like "RidePlus needs your location so that drivers know where to pick you up"; this explains *why* location is needed

Comment: For play store you need to submit the permissions declaration which you can find in the menu at the bottom left of the play console

Comment: For iOS, be sure to add these values: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52018518/9063088

Comment: @Paulw11
my app is for shipping therefore I need location for delivery

Comment: Don't tell me.  Tell the user. That doesn't sound like a good enough reason to ask for *always* permission unless you are tracking the delivery driver.